# Using sharepoint Taxonomy values as sorting parameter in linq query

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

My problem is as follows:

1. I am sorting IEnumerable<custItem> i.e. my customer list by using
   OrderByDescending.
2. I am getting output of above query as
   IOrderedEnumerable<custItem>.
3. After that I am sorting it using series of ThenByDescending queries. One of the query is using Sharepoint taxonomy field of type 'TaxonomyFieldValue'.

I am using following code for it:

```
                        orderedCustomerList = orderedCustomerList.ThenByDescending(o =>
                    {
                        if (o.Country != null && currentCustomerItem.Country != null)
                        {
                            if (o.Country.Label == currentCustomerItem.Country.Label)
                            {
                                return o;
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                        return null;
                    });
```

Some times I am getting following error - At least one one object must implement Icomparable.

Some times it works.

I also tried to use following code:

```
orderedCustomerList = orderedCustomerList.ThenByDescending(o => o.Country.ToString().Contains(currentCustomerItem.Country.Label));
```

Country is TaxonomyFieldValue type member of custItem class.

I get following error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I choose to answer this question instead of adding comments on it.
I converted this taxonomyFieldvalue type member of custItem class into taxonomyFieldvalueCollection by using following method:

```
private TaxonomyFieldValueCollection TaxonomyFieldToCollection(object item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            TaxonomyFieldValue temp = item as TaxonomyFieldValue;
            TaxonomyFieldValueCollection tempCol = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(temp.ValidatedString);
            return tempCol;
        }
        else
        {
            TaxonomyFieldValueCollection tempCol = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(string.Empty);
            tempCol.Clear();
            return tempCol;
        }
    }
```

Then I sorted using following command:

```
foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue value in currentCustomerItem.Country)
{
     orderedCustomerList = orderedCustomerList.ThenByDescending(o => o.Country.ToString().Contains(value.Label));
}
```

Thanks all of you.